# Trigger a loaded page's ready state

Tags: jquery

With JQuery I am trying to load a page in another, and have the ready state of that loaded page be triggered.

**Page1.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("Slides/page2.html");
});
```

**Page2.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("ready");
    //....
});
```

Is this possible?

If not, could I load page 2, and when loaded, trigger a named function IN page 2? (If so, how can I?)

Thanks,

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loaded page contents becomes part of the document itself, you don't get different document.

If the loaded page has function called `Foo()` simply calling it after it's loaded should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#content").load("Slides/page2.html", function() {
      Foo();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I tried, but I get a "ReferenceError: Can't fine variable: Foo" in the parent page. Any idea?

Comment: I had placed the function in the head section of the child page. I moved it to the body section, and the function triggered. How come it won't run it in head?

Comment: The `<head>` already exists in your document, so probably appending another `<head>` (which is what you effectively doing) is being ignored by the browser. Remember: the whole contents of the other page are copied **as-is** and pasted into the placeholder element.

Answer (score 0):

hey! From http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("Slides/page2.html",function(){
        alert('now page 2 is ready');
    });
});
```

Comment: H, I am actually trying to execute a function contained in the loaded page (page2.html), that is relevant only to that one page. As thus it will not be available in the parent until loaded.

Comment: u can just call it inside the callback function :) ..obv ur function in page2 must be visible ;)

Answer (score 0):

do this :

**Page1.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("Slides/page2.html",function(){
         alert('load')
    });
});
```